# joomla accordion module with sortable headings

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-sortable, joomla3.0

I have an issue with Joomla I've been battling with for a while now and I can't seem to see the answer. So I was hoping maybe someone out there might be able to help. First post so go easy on me.
I'm in the process of making a portfolio website for myself and can't seem to get my head around the SP_accordion module I'm using. I have it working and everything displaying everything it should and how it should.

I need, or should I say I also would like it to have a "header" with 3 columns that only effect the un-expanded accordion and are "sortable".

A perfect example of what I would like can be found @Jkarch.at

I have found an abundence of code for accordions and plenty of modules for joomla but I can't for the life of me find any help to create a 3 column accordion module for joomla 3. I'm not the most brilliant at web based applications or coding but I believe I can and usually do figure the most out myself but this is kicking my A*S.

So if anyone has a spare minute or to help it would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks again...

Chris.

Comment: You should include code of what you have already done, not linking to somewhere else for the community to find it.

Comment: I'm running my Joomla site on a local server :S how would I link what I've done? I'm seriously asking not trying to sound smart.

Comment: How about using the row-fluid span12 and create a three column layout grid (3 x span4) inside of it, setting positions acc1, acc2 and acc3. Then you can duplicate your accordion module and publish them in each position. That's just a suggestion...

Comment: I can throw in the code from the site but would be kinda of useless as I'd just be copying the German dudes code. I was kinda hoping that someone might chime in with known module or plugin that could do what i need/want. I'll keep pluging away.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your post, I'll give it a go and see what happens :) thanks